# Systems on network can be seen but cannot be accessed

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, network-shares

I want to enable file sharing for some of the systems in my network. However, I'm facing a weird issue.
Some of the systems can see each other on the network and share files with each other without any problems. other systems however, cannot connect to any systems but others can connect to them. Like this:
`System X CAN connect to System Y and see shared files and folders`.
`System Y CAN NOT connect to ANY system to see shared files and folders`.
there are multiple systems that have this issue. Here is what i tried so far:
1-Enable any file sharing options in `"Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings"`
2-Issue ping commands to and from faulty systems(they can ping and be pinged)
3-Try `\\192.168.0.xxx` to connect to other systems from faulty systems (did not work)  
4-Try to connect to faulty systems with the same Version number to see if that's the problem (it was not)
These problematic systems cannot connect to each other either.
Systems specs for some of the systems are :
Dell Inspiron 17R (Windows 10 X64 Version 1809) (cannot connect to others)
Acer Aspire 5749 (Windows 10 X64 Version 1903) (cannot connect to others)
Samsung NP470R5E (Windows 10 X64 Version 1809 ) (can connect and can be connected to)
Just to note: other systems DO show up on systems that cannot connect to anything else, but when I click them I get an error saying "Windows cannot access \COMPUTERNAME" with error code 0x80070035
EDIT: here is a wireshark capture from a failed attmept: [image: here] is a wireshark capture from a failed attempt

Comment: Do the failing connection attempts generate any packets on TCP port 445?

Comment: @grawity i believe they do, as the picture shows there are some packets traveled before remote host issues a RST